# Adding / Removing components on the fly

Tags: angular, dynamic, components, dispose

I need to be able to add & remove Angular components on the fly. To do so, I'm using loadIntoLocation and dispose methods, like it:

Adding a component (from a layout manager):

```
this.m_loader.loadIntoLocation(MyComponent, this.m_element, 'content').then(_componentRef => {

    // Create the window and set its title:
    var component: MyComponent = (_componentRef.instance);
    component.ref = _componentRef;

    // init the component content
});
```

Removing a component (from the component):

```
this.ref.dispose();
```

It is nearly working:
- if I add a component, and close it, it works
- if I add several components, they work
- but if I add component A, then remove it, then add component B, it seems like Angular gives me a reference to A, and keeps some old values (my components are draggable, and in this case the B will be created A was when I destroyed it)

Is there a way to make Angular destroy components properly, or at least to force it to create fresh ones?

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior in a plnkr? I have [this one working](http://plnkr.co/edit/z9xu3x2jVAEaoJq6TbRB?p=preview), but I'm not able (and I don't know really) how to reproduce your issue

Comment: Yep, I forked your plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/lvQfnLfTImcRqRcxJaXU?p=preview . Click "Add new component", drag it somewhere, click "Remove", then click "Add new component" again : the component is created at the just removed one place.

Comment: The problem seems to be that angular2 by default reuses the created DOM elements (took it from [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4795#issuecomment-151688714)). So if in your bootstrap you set `provide(APP_VIEW_POOL_CAPACITY, {useValue: 0}` it will work nicely. Here's the [plnkr updated](http://plnkr.co/edit/bqo9K5bru4CN1jZ4r9mt?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks, it solves the problem! You can add it as an answer, I'll select it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested by Tim,

quoting @tbosch's [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4795#issuecomment-151688714)

> Angular reuses previously created DOM elements by default

So to avoid this behavior, taken from the comment as well, you can use `APP_VIEW_POOL_CAPACITY` and assign it `0` as value.

```js
bootstrap(MyApp, [provide(APP_VIEW_POOL_CAPACITY, {useValue: 0})])
```

## Update

Note that since beta.1 `APP_VIEW_POOL_CAPACITY` was removed by [#5993](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/5993) and the DOM is being recreated correctly.