# How to destroy all the Components created using DynamicComponentLoader in angular2?

Tags: typescript, angular

Hie...I found a post regarding Adding and removing of components using Dynamic Component Loader and Dispose Method. I want to destroy the components created all at once. I have the plunker [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/7QrfTm4wDeR7NCZkAN6r?p=preview) and the source where i found the demo [Angular 2 - Adding / Removing components on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093670/angular-2-adding-removing-components-on-the-fly/34134651) ...
I know that i want to store all the `componentref` in an array then iterate them and dispose it...But i am not able to make it work...Please help me how to destroy all the components.

```
     remove() {
    this._ref.dispose();
  }
```

this is how i destroy a single component...How to destroy all at once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way to do what you're asking how to do is to keep track of the `ComponentRef`s as you add them and call `dispose()` on each in a loop when you want to remove them. See [updated plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/l5HQim7E8h8Zyw4etXzY?p=preview)

```
export class App {
  ...
  private _children:ComponentRef[] = [];

  add() {
    this._dcl.loadIntoLocation(DynamicCmp, this._e, 'location').then((ref) => {
      ...
      this._children.push(ref);
    });
  }

  removeall(){
    this._children.forEach(cmp=>cmp.dispose());
    this._children = []; // not even necessary to get the components off the screen
  }
}
```

If for some reason it's super important that you only call  `dispose()` once, you could create a "container", add your `DynamicComponent`s as children of that, and then dispose the container, automatically disposing its children.

Having said that,  I can't imagine a situation where I'd prefer doing that over adding the four lines of code it takes to implement what I outlined above...

Having said *all* that: **If there's a way to use data binding to do what you're trying to do, you should favor that over falling back on `DynamicComponentLoader` unless you have a damn good reason not to.**

I'll be the first to tell you there *are* use-cases where DCL is needed, but in my (albeit brief) experience, for every five I initially thought needed it, I came up with data-binding solutions for at least three after giving it a little thought.

In this case, doing that was trivial - see [other updated plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0OzBNJwfOrO2XZGz6JKQ?p=preview):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template : `
    <button (click)="add()">Add new component</button>
    <button (click)="removeAll()">Remove All</button>
    <template ngFor #child [ngForOf]="children">
       <div [dynamicCmp]="child"></div>
    </template>
  `,
  directives:[DynamicCmp]
})
export class App {
  children:number[] = [];

  add() {
    this.children.push(this.children.length+1);
  }

  removeAll(){
    this.children = [];
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance brother

Comment: **update**

`.dispose()` is `destroy()` **since beta.16**

Comment: well that was quick, @GünterZöchbauer :-P I started to edit my answer to reflect this, but I'd have to edit the question too. I haven't looked into this API change yet - would changing all references to `destroy()` in the question and answer alter the semantics of either?

Comment: Actually no, `loadIntoLocation` was removed and `loadNextToLocation` takes a `ViewContainerRef` instead of an `ElementRef`. I don't know if the CHANGELOG.md was already updated. You can search my answers (I'm on the phone). I updated a few related answers yesterday.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35171088/217408, https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8241/files