# How to call an event in parent component from child component which is loaded using DCL loadintolocation()

Tags: angular

I have an event in parent component. I want to call that event from the a child component created using DCL `loadintolocation()`. I am following this logic in the child component to raise the event

```ts
@Output() myevent1: EventEmitter;
onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.myForm.value);
  this.myevent1.emit();
}
```

I am able to raise the events for components which are already mentioned but not to components that are created using DCL. Please tell me how to raise the event in parent component from components created dynamically.

Here is the plunker demo i have worked till now http://plnkr.co/edit/2LJL4HxSc74XAyGmQMio?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you load the component, you can subscsribe to the event of the child from where you can call the parent function.

```
dcl.loadIntoLocation(ChildComponent, elementRef, 'child')
  .then((newComponent) => {
    newComponent.instance.event.subscribe(() => { .. call your parent ..});
  })
```

UPDATE

see the plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/DNmtl6TG5s2dsEUlVTvw?p=preview

Comment: Gunter's answer is good if you know the parent from the child. But if you want to load any component which are unknown and you know just the event, than with this you can achieve it without coupling.

Comment: well Gunter's answer is also good but i dont want to mention the parent component in child...Can you give me a plunker demo because in your answer there is no where i am mention the parent component in child...Please bro

Comment: Yea i will unsubscribe them when not necessary

Answer (score 4):

**update beta.16**

`dcl.loadIntoLocation()` now needs a `ViewContainerRef` instead of a template variable name.

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'dynamic',
    template: `
    <h1 (click)="null">I'm the dynamic component</h1>
    <button (click)="someEvent.emit($event)">click me</button>
    `,
})
export class DynamicComponent {
  someEvent = new EventEmitter();
}
```

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <div>
      <div>clicked at (top): {{top}}</div>
      <span>dynamic component below</span>
      <div #target></div>
    </div>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target;
  top;

  constructor(private dcl:DynamicComponentLoader) {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dcl.loadNextToLocation(DynamicComponent, this.target)
    .then(ref => {
      ref.instance.someEvent
      .subscribe(value => {
        console.log(value.clientX);
        this.top = value.clientX; 
        console.log(this.top);
      })
    });
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example beta.17**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CcKXhq?p=preview)

**original**

With

```ts
loadIntoLocation(
    SomeComponent, 
    someElementRef, 
    'someAnchor',
    [/*other providers, */
        provide(ParentComponent, useValue: this)]);
```

you can pass the parent component to the dynamically created component.

In the child component you just add the parent to the constructor parameter list

```ts
constructor(parent: ParentComponent) {}
```

To not couple parent and child so tightly you can also use a shared service and pass this instead of the parent component itself.