# How to pass an object from parent component to child component which is created using DCL loadintolocation()?

Tags: angular

I am loading a component using DCL.I want to pass an object into that component.. I have made a plunker demo http://plnkr.co/edit/QKlMNnjfrt8PyVnGdJG4?p=preview where AppComponent is the parent and this the object i want to pass  `information = {name:"Abhi", place:"Banglore"};`

```
export class SomeComponent {
public childform: ControlGroup;
constructor(fbs: FormBuilder) {  
this.childform = fbs.group({  
  'name':  ['', Validators.required],
  'place':['']
});
}

}
```

This is the child component...When ever new component loads i want to display the object passed in input box of child component.I have no idea how to pass the data from parent to child in DCL...Somebody please help me guys...

Answer (score 2):

The [ComponentRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ComponentRef-class.html) provides a reference to the created component by it's `instance` getter

```
loadIntoLocation(...).then(ref => {
  ref.instance.someField = someValue;
}
```

See also this similar question [How to call an event in parent component from child component which is loaded using DCL loadintolocation()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35170985/how-to-call-an-event-in-parent-component-from-child-component-which-is-loaded-us)

Comment: When i try to get the instance of ref.instance.items.results  it is showing undefined in my console window

Comment: This is from `FakeComponent` right? `@QueryList` is only filled after `ngAfterViewInit()` AFAIK. You could add an `EventEmitter` to `FakeComponent` that sends an event when `ngAfterViewInit()` is executed. Then you could wait like `ref.instance.afterViewInitCalled.subscribe(value => { ref.instance.items.result...});`