# ViewChild on html rendered as innerHtml

Tags: angular, viewchild

I would like to access an element with ViewChild that is rendered with innerHtml, but in the lifecycle hook AfterViewInit, logging the element return undefined.

Below is the code used:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: `<p [innerHTML]="'<ng-template #innerHtmlNgTemplate></ng-template>' | safeHtml"></p>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('innerHtmlNgTemplate') public innerHtmlNgTemplate;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.innerHtmlNgTemplate); // undefined
  }
}
```

The question is how can I access the `<ng-template></ng-template>` with ViewChild or in another way?

Cheers

EDIT:

Here is a stackblitz showing the issue. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k1xeh6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

EDIT2:

In the stackblitz I sanitized the html, if this isn't done the ids are removed.

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: @Rajat Here is a stackblitz of the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k1xeh6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is you should **not** do this. Angular is not designed to work this way.

This is the partial response from the angular issue thread.

---

*When you insert HTML string through innerHTML, such string is not processed by Angular. As such you can't expect any Angular syntax / functionality (including queries) to work - simply put Angular has no chance of processing static HTML inserted into innerHTML. In this respect the observed behaviour "works as designed".*

*I'm not sure what your exact, functional use-case is but the scenario you've exposed is not something that Angular supports today and quite honestly, this is not how it was designed in the first place.*

Github issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35874

Answer (score 0):

Try Specifying the type for Viewchild (try below code)

```
  @ViewChild('innerHtmlNgTemplate') innerHtmlNgTemplate: ElementRef;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried doing this, but the console log is still undefined. FYI: I added a stackblitz in the original post showing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to have reference to ng-template

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: `<p  
  [innerHTML]="'This is the innerhtml, and the following tag I want to select with ViewChild: '" >
     <ng-template #innerHtmlNgTemplate></ng-template>
  </p>

 `
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('innerHtmlNgTemplate', {static: true}) public innerHtmlNgTemplate;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.innerHtmlNgTemplate); // find value
  }
}
```

And use this if you want to reference innerHTML without changing the template

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: `<p  #innerHtmlNgTemplate
  [innerHTML]="'This is the innerhtml, and the following tag I want to select with ViewChild: <ng-template ></ng-template>'"></p>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('innerHtmlNgTemplate', {static: true}) public innerHtmlNgTemplate;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.innerHtmlNgTemplate.nativeElement.innerHTML); // prints innerhtml
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think it would be good if I explain my goal. I get an HTML template from the backend. In this template, there will be a tag say `<ng-template #dynamicComponent></ng-template>`. This tag I want to replace with an Angular component. My plan is to get the <ng-template> tag with ViewChild and replace the tag with the actual component.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if you need something else

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892632/angular2-replacing-component-dynamically-inside-another-component

Comment: The big difference from what they do in the StackOverflow thread mentioned above is that the <placeholder></placeholder> tag is *not* rendered inside of an innerHtml.