# Angular2 remove component programmatically.

Tags: angular

I have a service, which create new blade and save it in blades array. I show this blade using "DynamicComponentLoader". 
Now i want to delete my blade, from another blade. But how i can do that?

Comment: The answer:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585357/how-to-destroy-all-the-components-created-using-dynamiccomponentloader-in-angula](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585357/how-to-destroy-all-the-components-created-using-dynamiccomponentloader-in-angula)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to destroy all the Components created using DynamicComponentLoader in angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585357/how-to-destroy-all-the-components-created-using-dynamiccomponentloader-in-angula)

Answer (score 6):

```ts
export class YourComponent {
  constructor(private ref:ElementRef) {}

  someFunc() {
    elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('some-elem').destroy();
  }
}
```

You could also use a wrapper element

```ts
<div #wrapper><dynamic-component></dynamic-component>
```

then use

```ts
@ViewChild('wrapper') wrapper;
...
someFunc() {
  while (myNode.firstChild) {
    myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Günter Zöchbauer. But this is delete from DOM. For example, if i have ngOnDestroy() in component, it doesnt perform. Angular dont know that the component was deleted.

Comment: @АлексейСерафимов: You could use the approach described in http://stackoverflow.com/q/34093670/4715679 – i.e.: pass a reference to the `ComponentRef` to the created component and invoke the `dispose()` method on it.

Comment: I was wondering if .remove() is the same as display: none or just removes a rendered element

Comment: @Mese `display: none` and `remove()` (now `destroy()`) are entirely different. `display: none` is CSS only and just makes the host element invisible and can made be visible by for example setting `display: block`, while `destroy()` destroys the component, removes the host element from the DOM and only can be re-added by using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`.