# Remove component itself

Tags: angular, typescript

I cant find out the solve if this problem.

I have 2 components:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template : `
   <product *ngFor="let prod of products" [product]='product'>
  `
})
export class App {
    public products =['object',object]; //its only example of products objects array
}

@Component({
      selector: 'product',
      template : `
      <p>{{product.name}}</p>
      `
    })

export class App {
    @Input() product:any;
}
```

Right now how can i delete one specyfic product component? May be component can do this itself? 
I check this posts and still dont have any idea
[Angular 2 - Adding / Removing components on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093670/angular-2-adding-removing-components-on-the-fly) and [How to destroy all the Components created using DynamicComponentLoader in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585357/how-to-destroy-all-the-components-created-using-dynamiccomponentloader-in-angula)

In app the product list will be downloaded from serwer and displayed like this. I want to add a button to remove single product it self from the list. Right now i have a function which deletes  this product from server but i think its a stupid idea to download the list of product again. So i think it will be beter remove it from from the DOM maybe with ElemntRef or ComponentRef

Comment: `products` is just a local copy. If you remove it from there, it's not removed from the server. This doesn't sound at all like a use case to remove the element yourself. In Angular2 the preferred way is to update the model and let directives like `*ngFor`, `*ngIf`, `*ngSwitchCase` do the DOM updating.

Comment: I have a funtion which deletes product on server but i dont want to reload a list again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the item from `products` and the `<product>` component will be removed by `*ngFor`.

Besides that, there is no way to remove components added by Angular2. You can only remove components that you added yourself.

Comment: In app the product list will be downloaded from serwer and displayed like this. I want to add a button to remove single product it self from the list. Right now i have a function which deletes this product from server but i think its a stupid idea to download the list of product again. So i think it will be beter remove it from from the DOM maybe with ElemntRef or ComponentRef

Comment: See my comment above. There is no need to download again. Just send a command to the server to delete it there and also delete it in the `products` array. This way you don't need to fetch the data again and Angular2 will take care the component gets removed.

Comment: This is it ! Thanks You :)