# Angular2 - Can't add child component after deleting all/recent child components

Tags: javascript, angular

I am adding child components through a button in the parent component dynamically. It works fine and I can add as many child as I want but as soon as I delete the last child (just added) , adding a new child doesn't work anymore.

Here is how I am doing it:

**parent.ts**

```
import {Component,DynamicComponentLoader,ElementRef,AfterViewInit,Injector} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ChildComponent} from './child.ts';


@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    host: {'id':'children'},
    template: `<button (click)="addChild()" >Add Child</button><div #here></div>`
})
class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
    public counter = 0;
    constructor(private _loader:DynamicComponentLoader,private _elementRef:ElementRef) {}
    addChild(){
        var app = this;
        this._loader.loadIntoLocation(ChildComponent,this._elementRef,'here').then(child => {
            child.instance.id = app.counter++;
        });
    }

}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

**child.ts**

```
import {Component,OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: "div",
    host: {'[attr.id]':'id'},
    template: "Child Component <button (click)='remove()' >Remove Me</button>"
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit{
    public id:number;

    remove(){
        $("#"+this.id).remove();
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you preproduce it on plnkr? https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update**

`.dispose()` is `destroy()` **since beta.16**

**original**

I think you should use

```
child.dispose();
```

instead of removing the tags using jQuery.

See also [Angular 2 - Adding / Removing components on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093670/angular-2-adding-removing-components-on-the-fly/34134651)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `dispose` method on the `ComponentRef` class to remove your component.

For this, you need to provide it to the component instance itself this way:

```
addChild(){
    var app = this;
    this._loader.loadIntoLocation(ChildComponent,this._elementRef,'here').then(child => {
        child.instance.id = app.counter++;
        child.instance.ref = child;
    });
}
```

And use it like that in your component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "div",
  host: {'[attr.id]':'id'},
  template: "Child Component <button (click)='remove()' >Remove Me</button>"
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit{
  public id:number;

  remove(){
    this.ref.dispose();
  }
};
```