# How can I use an event emitter on a dynamically added component?

Tags: angular

Working off of Eric Martinez' answer from [Angular 2 - Adding / Removing components on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093670/angular-2-adding-removing-components-on-the-fly), I want to limit the amount of components created. And then after deleting a component, I'm trying to emit that event to the parent so the parent knows the number of components currently created.

In this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oLPyr1I9Y6YmYpHjfvXJ?p=preview), I limit the number of components by 4, and then I'm trying to emit an event to lower that count back down. The event isn't emitting. How do you emit an event from a dynamically added component?

```
// dynamic component
@Component({
    selector : 'dynamic',
    template : `
    <div>
        Component number {{_idx}} <button (click)="remove()">Remove</button>
    </div>`
})
class DynamicCmp {
    _ref: ComponentRef;
    _idx: number;
    @Output lowerIndex = new EventEmitter<any>();
    remove() {
        this._ref.dispose();
        this.lowerIndex.emit(true);
    }
}

// Parent container component    
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template : `
        <button (click)="add()">Add new component</button>
        <div #location (lowerIndex)="lowerIndex();"></div>
    `
})
export class App {
    idx: number = 0;
    constructor(private _dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, private _e: ElementRef) {}

    lowerIndex() {
        this.idx--;
        console.log("subtracted");
    }

    add() {
        if (this.idx < 4) {
            this._dcl.loadIntoLocation(DynamicCmp, this._e, 'location').then((ref) => {
            ref.instance._ref = ref;
            ref.instance._idx = this.idx++;
            });

            console.log("added")
        }
    }
}
```

I posted the components in here because stackoverflow requires code posted with plunker links. Code is exactly the same as seen in plunker

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The issue here is that dynamically loaded components don't have a parent / child relationship with the components where they're loaded in. That's why to access properties from the dynamically loaded component you have to use `ref.instance.property`. The component is not being compiled along with the parent, therefore the parent knows nothing about the *foster* component.

Now, that being said, what you can do is to make a property that you can subscribe to and [I wouldn't use an EventEmitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter) for that.

My solution would be to use a Subject instead (as I'm doing in a little project of my own).

Your dynamic component would look like this

```js
class DynamicCmp {

    // Subject instead of an EventEmitter
    lowerIndex: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

    remove() {
        // We send true, although in the example is not being used
        this.lowerIndex.next(true);

        // Remove the component from the view
        this._ref.dispose();
    }
}
```

Your component where you're loading the dynamic component

```js
template : '<div #location></div>'; // Note that I removed (lowerIndex)="..."
this._dcl.loadIntoLocation(DynamicCmp, this._e, 'location').then((ref) => {
    //...

    // Subscribe to the Subject property
    ref.instance.lowerIndex.subscribe(v => {
        this.idx--;
        console.log("subtracted");
    });
});
```

Here's your [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8qpQ6Tk6LG3n0I2jXS4X?p=preview) working and updated to beta.12.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your help Eric :)

Comment: *Foster* component: Very aptly put.

Comment: Good solution !

Comment: Works like a charm! I live to someday be the kind of person that posts these answers ;P

Comment: But what if I am planning to use this as both a dynamic component in one place and as a child component of a parent in another? Should I use EventEmitter.subscribe() then so that this component is reusable in many places?